# Nested combineReducers produce an undefined value

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to nest my reducers to give this structure:

```
state: {
  data: {
     dataSetOne: {
       items: [],
       filter: {
         query: "",
         includeInactive: false
       } 
     }
  }
}
```

My file structure is:

```
--reducers
  |__index.js
  |__data
    |__dataSetOne.js
```

In `index.js` I import `dataSetOne.js` and export `combineReducers({ dataSetOne })`. This works just fine. However, in `dataSetOne.js` I can't seem to nest `filter`. What I have:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

function items (state = [], action) {
  ...
}

function query (state = "", action) {
  ...
}

function includeInactive (state = false, action) {
  ...
}

export default combineReducers({
  filter: combineReducers({
    includeInactive,
    query
  }),
  items
});
```

Part of this works; I can access `state.data.dataSetOne.items` with no problem. However, `filter` is `undefined`. It doesn't even exist on the `dataSetOne` object.

I must be misunderstanding how `combineReducers` works, but I can't figure out why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out! I'm using `redux-persist` with `localforage` to persist my store across refreshes. Apparently this was somehow causing the issue. I cleared the `localforage` database and everything works as expected.

I still must not be completely understanding how `combineReducers` works, though, because I can add simple `function`s to my reducers without having to clear the storage.

If anyone can explain this behavior, I'll mark it as the answer.